# Avoid adding another '\0' if string already has one?

Tags: c, string, strlen

it is not clear if **`+ 1`** is needed or not here:

```
int len = strlen(TARGET);
info = malloc( len + 1 );
```

because few lines above it it already was once appended to it:

```
TARGET[END - START] = '\0';
```

if it is needed then perhaps also.. appending the `\0` is needed.

```
int len = strlen(TARGET);
info = malloc( len + 1 );
strcpy(info, TARGET);
info[len] = '\0';
```

> **Q**:  How to determine if a string already has the `null termination`

perhaps if it already has it.. appending another one wouldn't be logic.

full function :

```
char * FUNCTION ( char * v ){

char *TARGET = NULL;
const char *PATTERN1 = "co=";
const char *PATTERN2 = "&";
char *START = strstr(v, PATTERN1);

if (START) {
START = START + strlen(PATTERN1);
char *END = strstr(START, PATTERN2);
if (!END){
END = START + strlen(START);
}
TARGET = malloc(END - START + 1);
memcpy(TARGET, START, END - START);
TARGET[END - START] = '\0';
}

if (!START || TARGET == NULL || TARGET[0] == '\0') {
return 0;
}

int len = strlen(TARGET);
info = malloc( len + 1 );
strcpy(info, TARGET);
info[len] = '\0';

return info;
}
```

Comment: "How to determine if a string already has the null termination" You couldn't use `strlen` if the string weren't null-terminated.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Hey, I'm not sure of other questions, but this looks like a legitimate question (I'm not judging the quality, though).

Comment: i am afraid there is a mistaken identity crisis in effect here perhaps.

Comment: my posts are being trolled by such invalid comments.

Comment: the damage is being done to the people that invested time to post answers. the damage is not done to the OP. the intent of the Poster is to solve a question.

Comment: @FelixPalmen A wise man once said "Don't feed the troll please". His name was Felix Palmen.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca got you.

Comment: Try and use fewer UPPERCASE identifiers.

Answer (score 5):

> *How to determine if a string already has the null termination*

Well, a "string", is by definition, null-terminated. Otherwise, it is not a *string*.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.1.1

> A string is a contiguous sequence of characters **terminated by and including** the first null
>   character. [....]

From theoretical point of view, it's the responsibility of the producer, not the consumer, to ensure the null-termination for a character array which is supposed to be used as string.

---

That said, `strlen()` returns the length of a *string*, without the null-terminator. So, if you were to use the return value of `strlen()` of an existing string to allocate memory for a copy thereof, you need to allocate one extra bye for the null-terminator, so the `+1` is required while passing the size to allocator function.

Answer (score 3):

`strlen` calculates how many characters there are in a string up to and excluding the `\0`, so you'll never count it. So for example if you string is `"hello"`, its `strlen` would be 5. So yes, you'll always need to add 1 to its length to account for the `\0` at the end.

Comment: `if strlen returns a correct value, the string is null-terminated for sure`...welcome to the world of UB.

Comment: Now that you say it, it seems obvious. I removed that part.

Answer (score 1):

The following:

```
int len = strlen(TARGET);
```

will not give you `sizeof(TARGET)`; it will just count the number of characters before the first `\0`.  So, if `TARGET` contains `"a\0bcd"` it will give you just 1 (for `'a'`).

The following:

```
 info = malloc( len +1 );
```

Needs to allocate enough bytes for the string plus the null terminator, so the `+ 1` is necessary.

The following:

```
strcpy(info, TARGET);
```

will copy characters until the first `'\0'` is encountered, *and then it will append a `'\0'`*, so there must be enough space in the destination for the `'\0'`.